# Disabling selection of dates in a date field

Tags: gwt, gxt, datefield

I'm using a date field in which I want to limit the date selection to a maximum of 90 days from the current date. How can i achieve this?

I tried `dateField.setMaxvalue(maxDate)`, but I'm not able to limit the selection

Comment: I believe, you have more of a chance to get an answer, if you post the code you have so far.

Comment: if it is your input cell than may be you can extend it and override onBrowserEvent() and isEditing() method to provide your logic to prevent user from enter more than 90 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the GWT datepicker has support for this.
You could use a library like GWT-Bootstrap3 which does have all this (https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#dateTimePicker).

Or you could listen for events and rollback changes made by the user if selection was outside the valid range, and display a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I second to the suggestion given by @Knarf. You could use GWT DatePicker class and listen for a ValueChangeEvent and in ValueChangeHandler, you could put your logic to check if the selected date is within your range - if not, you could show a message on your UI for the User to reselect a date within the date range (as per your requirement).

```
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    final Label text = new Label();

    // Listen for a ValueChangeEvent and implement a ValueChangeHandler on your datePicker element
    datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
      public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> valueChangeEvent) {
        Date inputDate = valueChangeEvent.getValue();

        // Put your logic to test whether the selected date is within your range
        String dateString = DateTimeFormat.getMediumDateFormat().format(inputDate);
        text.setText(dateString);
      }
    });
```

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [ShowRangeHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html#addShowRangeHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ShowRangeHandler%29) to your datePicker. This is an example to restrict the datePicker to dates in the past only, you can adapt it to limit to 90 days:

```
datePicker.addShowRangeHandler(new ShowRangeHandler<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void onShowRange(ShowRangeEvent<Date> event) {
            Date today = new Date();
            Date date = new Date(event.getStart().getTime());
            while (date.before(event.getEnd())) {
                if (date.after(today) && datePicker.isDateVisible(date)) {
                    datePicker.setTransientEnabledOnDates(false, date);
                }

                CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(date, 1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned solutions  worked exactly the way i expected..Thank you.I used the bootstrap datepicker in the link (https://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#dateTimePicker).